# How to save a report's result as a csv document in salesforce

Tags: automation, custom-reports, document

I have a report that needs to run monthly and save its result as a CSV document inside salesforce. The report is currently scheduled to run and send the result as an email but the request is to change this behavior and save the CSV in salesforce. Is there a way to do this within the report itself or use a flow?

I know that [apex allows you to get the report's results](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_analytics_report_data.htm) and then in apex I can form a CSV and save it as a content document but I'd like to see if I can do this without using the apex code. Thanks!

Comment: Save the CSV as a Salesforce File?

Comment: I guess you could email it to an email-to-case address and then use a flow to handle the attachment from there on but that sound convoluted. To be honest, assuming it's only one file a month, I wouldn't bother automating it.

Comment: [Snapshots](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_about_analytic_snap.htm&type=5) are the solution to recording history.